why isn't LED flashing for my microcontroller set up?
I am struggling with the simplest program. I am working with PIC microcontroller and am trying to get the LED to blink with MCC configure in MPLAB. There aren't many steps involved in this yet I can't figure out why my LED is not flashing. The steps, according to this video MCC melody Timer0 PLIB driver: 100ms Timer - Youtube are:
1)Open up MCC melody
2)select Timer0 from Device resources>drivers>Timer panel and add it

3)select Fosc/4 (internal oscillator) and enable interrupt


4)configure a pin for output blinking


5)Hit "Generate Code" and then create a pointer to Timer0 struct and pass Timer_call_back_10us (this is the time that falls into the range set by Timer0 in MCC melody from step 3) into argument of TimeoutCallbackRegister. toggle LED pin RA5.
6)enable global interrupt
#include "mcc_generated_files/system/system.h"
const struct TMR_INTERFACE *Timer= &Timer0;
/*
Main application
*/
void Timer_Callback_10us(void){
LED_Toggle();
 }
 int main(void)
 {
 SYSTEM_Initialize();
 Timer->TimeoutCallbackRegister(Timer_Callback_10us);
 // If using interrupts in PIC18 High/Low Priority Mode you need to 
 enable the Global High and Low Interrupts 
 // If using interrupts in PIC Mid-Range Compatibility Mode you need to 
 enable the Global and Peripheral Interrupts 
 // Use the following macros to: 

 // Enable the Global Interrupts 
 INTERRUPT_GlobalInterruptEnable(); 

 // Disable the Global Interrupts 
 //INTERRUPT_GlobalInterruptDisable(); 

 // Enable the Peripheral Interrupts 
 INTERRUPT_PeripheralInterruptEnable(); 

 // Disable the Peripheral Interrupts 
 //INTERRUPT_PeripheralInterruptDisable(); 


 while(1)
 {
 }    
 }

The code for the timer struct callback register comes from the timer0.c created after generating the MCC melody code. Here it is:
#include <xc.h>
#include "../tmr0.h"

volatile uint8_t timer0ReloadVal;

const struct TMR_INTERFACE Timer0 = {
.Initialize = Timer0_Initialize, 
.Start = NULL,
.Stop = NULL,
.PeriodCountSet = Timer0_PeriodCountSet,
.TimeoutCallbackRegister = Timer0_OverflowCallbackRegister,
.Tasks = NULL
};

static void (*Timer0_OverflowCallback)(void);
static void Timer0_DefaultOverflowCallback(void);

void Timer0_Initialize(void)
{
// PS 1:2; PSA not_assigned; TMRSE Increment_hi_lo; TMRCS FOSC/4; mask 
the nWPUEN and INTEDG bits
OPTION_REG = (uint8_t)((OPTION_REG & 0xC0) | (0xD8 & 0x3F));

// TMR 0; 
TMR0 = 0x0;

// Load the TMR value to reload variable
timer0ReloadVal = 0;

//Set default callback for TMR0 overflow interrupt
Timer0_OverflowCallbackRegister(Timer0_DefaultOverflowCallback);

//Clear Interrupt flag before enabling the interrupt
INTCONbits.TMR0IF = 0;

//Enable TMR0 interrupt.
INTCONbits.TMR0IE = 1;

}

uint8_t Timer0_Read(void)
{
uint8_t readVal;

readVal = TMR0;

return readVal;
}

void Timer0_Write(size_t timerVal)
{
// Write to the Timer0 register
TMR0 = (uint8_t) timerVal;
}

void Timer0_Reload(void)
{
// Write to the Timer0 register
TMR0 = timer0ReloadVal;
}

void Timer0_PeriodCountSet(size_t periodVal)
{
timer0ReloadVal = (uint8_t) periodVal;
}

void Timer0_OverflowISR(void)
{

//Clear the TMR0 interrupt flag
INTCONbits.TMR0IF = 0;

TMR0 = timer0ReloadVal;
if(Timer0_OverflowCallback)
{
  Timer0_OverflowCallback();
}
}

void Timer0_OverflowCallbackRegister(void (* CallbackHandler)(void))
{ 
Timer0_OverflowCallback = CallbackHandler;
}

static void Timer0_DefaultOverflowCallback(void)
{
//Add your interrupt code here or
//Use Timer0_OverflowCallbackRegister function to use Custom ISR
}

7)I downloaded the program to the PIC

8)I got the following error
The configuration is set for the target board to supply its own power 
but no voltage has been detected on VDD. Please ensure you have your 
target powered up and try again.
Connection Failed.

To get around this error. I simply opened MPLAB IPE
I clicked power settings and made sure the PICkit5 votlage was set

then I clicked connect

The following message (sorry. there wasn't an error here) showed up

edit: i changed the prescalar to 1:256 (16ms) and the LED is still not blinking

Hello ... We don't know what you have or what you've tried or what you do see.  It would really help to have a bit more information: do you have a circuit diagram of what you're using, or even a photo of the circuit?  Do you get any behaviour at all?  If so, what?

The LED isn't flashing so there is no behavior.

is the LED connected correctly?

please remove the pictures of code and replace them with code text

Yes, the LED is connected correctly. + side to the pin and - side to the gnd rail on the bread board. the gnd rail is the same rail VSS is connected to. VSS is connected to gnd on the PICkit5.

Your eyes will not interpret a 10 µs (or 64 µs) LED toggle interval as flashing.

The LED should appear to stay on if it is flashing that fast right?

I changed it to 16ms. This is the slowest the prescaler (1:256) allows me to go. The LED is still not blinking.

16 ms is not blinking, it is flickering ... don't look at it directly ... your eyes are more sensitive to motion on the sides of your field of view ... you may be able to detect flickering out of the corner of your eye

"8)I got the following error
The configuration is set for the target board to supply its own power
but no voltage has been detected on VDD. Please ensure you have your
target powered up and try again.
Connection Failed."
You really should have a power supply for your target board. If you insist to powering your target board through the PICkit 5, do the following:

On the left panel, select the project, then right-click and select Properties
Select the PICkit 5
On Option categories, select Power
Check the box for "Power target circuit from PICkit 5

16ms is still pretty fast. You may need to slow it down more.
Which PIC are you using?
I think this line:
Timer->TimeoutCallbackRegister(Timer_Callback_10us);
should be:
Timer0_OverflowCallbackRegister(Timer_Callback_10us);

If you look at my entire post, you will notice I followed the powering steps you listed. I mispoke though. I meant I got the following message  - it wasn't an error, it showed that it worked.

Also, doesn't it do the same thing? The struct is defined as: const struct TMR_INTERFACE Timer0 = {
.Initialize = Timer0_Initialize,
.Start = NULL,
.Stop = NULL,
.PeriodCountSet = Timer0_PeriodCountSet,
.TimeoutCallbackRegister = Timer0_OverflowCallbackRegister,
.Tasks = NULL
}; by creating a pointer called Timer you can use the access operator to access whats inside the struct right?

I don't think so. Honestly, I don't see anywhere in the code where they actually use that structure. If you can see it let me know. They ARE using Timer0_OverflowCallback in the Timer0_OverflowISR(void) function, though.

they defined it at the top of the second code file as a member of a struct Timer0 ".TimeoutCallbackRegister = Timer0_OverflowCallbackRegister, " and then in the main file, there is a pointer to the struct, Timer0, that gets created called Timer. Timer accesses the member in the struct and passes the funciton Timer_Callback_10us to toggle the LED. this is how i understood it. i could be wrong.

Right. I saw those, but I don't see it or any of its members being used anywhere.
